# Split string on pattern coming first like ";;;" Explained in Post Java?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I want to break a string that has some unwanted characters initially and that has unlimited length.

For example:

```
;;;USA;23;john;;;USA:24;charles
```

The part I want is after the first ";;;", ie:

```
USA;23;john;;;USA:24;charles
```

I tried:

```
 inputtring1 = ";;;USA;23;john;;;USA:24;charles";
 String temp = inputString1.split(";;;")[1];
```

but it does not work; it shows result like

```
USA;23;john
```

";;;" may come in string in any number with other records. Above string is to make clear it's not in a fixed location.

Comment: Really "some" (=any) wrong character and really with "no limited length"? Most answers fail to handle that... Perhaps you add some other examples as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want everything after the first `";;;"`, just do this:

```
String stuff = str.replaceFirst(".*?;;;"), "");
```

A key point here is the *reluctant* quantifier `*?` which consumes as *little* as possible while still matching.

Comment: its working fine for ;;;USA;23;john;;;USA:24;charles but if i have ;;;USA;23;john;;;USA:24;charles;;;USA;25;mary it result me USA:24;charles;;;USA;25 ?

Comment: @user3664724 it works for me. It displays `USA;23;john;;;USA:24;charles;;;USA;25;mary`

Answer (score 0):

You could do it the old fashioned way:

```
int index = string.indexOf(";;;");
string = string.substring(index + 3);
```

or use the second argument of `split`:

```
string = string.split(";;;", 2)[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String Temp=inputString1.split(";;;",1);
```

will split it on the first occurrence alone. Check it [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) docs

Comment: The idea is there, but this is not going to compile.

Answer (score 0):

```
string.split(patternString, limit);
```

As String.split(String,int) explains:

> The array returned by this method contains each substring of this
>   string that is terminated by another substring that matches the given
>   expression or is terminated by the end of the string. The substrings
>   in the array are in the order in which they occur in this string. If
>   the expression does not match any part of the input then the resulting
>   array has just one element, namely this string.
>
> The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is
>   applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If
>   the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at
>   most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and
>   the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched
>   delimiter.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputString = ";;;USA;23;john;;;USA:24;charles";
        String temp = inputString.split(";;;", 2)[1];
        System.out.println(temp);
    }
```

**output**

```
USA;23;john;;;USA:24;charles
```

**Explanation**
`inputString.split(";;;", 2)` // pattern will be applied `(2-1)` times.

Answer (score 0):

If the first "wrong character" is *any* character, appearing in *any length*, do

```
    String stuff = str.replaceFirst("(.)\\1+", "");
```

Comment: Someone didn't understand this, obviously.